# how to change string into operator logical in query postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have a condition where I must save operator like 'AND' and 'OR' in my table.

```
id | name | upper | lower | operator
1  | limit | 10    | 1    | 'AND'
```

how do I can use that operator like usual from column table ? thank you

Answer (score 0):

With postgresql you can't basically convert a string 'AND' into the logical operator `AND`. What you can do is to test the column `operator` and write a conditon according to that value :

```
SELECT CASE 
         WHEN operator = 'AND'
         THEN write_here_your_AND_condional_statement
         WHEN operator = 'OR'
         THEN write_here_your_OR_condional_statement
         ELSE write_here_something_else
       END
  FROM your_table
```

Comment: yes I agree with you.

how about inside where clause ? 

`
select * from your_table where 1=1 and CASE 
         WHEN operator = 'AND'
         THEN write_here_your_AND_condional_statement
         end
or case when operator ='OR' then write_here_your_OR_condional_statement end
`

how about this code is it ok to separate case between and or operator ?

Comment: the right code is `SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE CASE WHEN operator = 'AND' THEN write_here_your_AND_condional_statement CASE WHEN operator ='OR' THEN write_here_your_OR_condional_statement END`